# Could not create symlink for "/Users"

Tags: mac, symlink

I want to create symbolic link for /Users to /home. So i tried to execute `ln -s \Users \home`. which gave me error `ln: /home/Users: Operation not supported`.

Any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do it as root, and use forward slashes:

```
$ ln -s /Users /home
$ ls -ld /Users /home
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  admin  204 Apr  8  2014 /Users
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel    6 Sep 17 15:49 /home -> /Users
```